# My custom mobilenet trained model is not showing any results. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow, semantic-segmentation, deeplab, mobilenet

I started to learn ML using Tensorflow/Deeplab. I tried to train my own model from scratch for clothes recognition using semantic segmentation with mobilenet_v2 model variant. But I don't get results.

I'm using [tensorflow/models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) for tfrecord export and training. And [deeplab/example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/deeplab_demo.ipynb) code for visualization and testing purpose (renamed locally as main.py), I modify some lines so I can get the local models and testing image.

I'll show the process I followed:

1. Download 100 JPEG images (I know is not that big, but I guess I can try it with this amount). Just for 1 class -> shirts
2. Create the segmentation class PNG for each image.
3. Create the files image sets definition for: train(85 filenames), trainval(100 filenames) and val(15 filenames).

   So my "pascal dataset" directory has: ImageSets, JPEGImages and SegmentationClassPNG folders.
4. Export the "pascal dataset" directory to tfrecord like this (I'm on "models-master/research/deeplab/datasets" folder):

   ```
   py build_voc2012_data.py --image_folder="pasc_imgs/JPEGImages" --semantic_segmentation_folder="pasc_imgs/SegmentationClassPNG" --list_folder="pasc_imgs/ImageSets" --image_format="jpg" --output_dir="train/tfrecord"
   ```

   - this works fine, it generates *.tfrecord files on "train/tfrecord"
5. I edited "models-master/research/deeplab/data_generator.py" like this: {'train': 85, 'trainval': 100, 'val': 15}, num_classes=2.
6. Now time to start the training, (I'm on "models-master/research/deeplab"). I used 10000 steps, why? I proved with 30000 and takes like 30 hours with no results, so I reduce it with new params. I guess 10000 steps could show me something:

   ```
   py train.py --logtostderr  --training_number_of_steps=10000 --train_split="train" --model_variant="mobilenet_v2" --output_stride=16 --decoder_output_stride=4 --train_batch_size=1 --dataset="pascal_voc_seg"  --train_logdir="datasets/train/deeplab_model_mn" --dataset_dir="datasets/train/tfrecord"
   ```

   - This step takes almost 8 hours (have a tiny GPU, so.. can't use it), and it generates the checkpoint, graph.pbtxt, and model.ckpt-XXX (10000 included) files.
7. I exported the previous result with (I'm on "models-master/research/deeplab") this command line:

   ```
   py export_model.py --checkpoint_path=datasets/train/deeplab_model_mn/model.ckpt-10000 --export_path=datasets/train/deeplab_inference_mn/frozen_inference_graph.pb --model_variant="mobilenet_v2" --output_stride=16 --num_classes=2
   ```

   - It creates the frozen graph (frozen_inference_graph.pb).
8. Now run: **py main.py** (proof image and frozen_inference_graph.pb already imported)
9. No results with my custom model. This last script works with pre-trained mobilenetv2_coco_voc_trainaug. Not with my custom model

**data_generator.py (edited lines):**

```py
_PASCAL_VOC_SEG_INFORMATION = DatasetDescriptor(
    splits_to_sizes={
        'train': 85,
        'trainval': 100,
        'val': 15,
    },
    num_classes=2,# 0:background, 1:shirt
    ignore_label=255,
)
```

Image example (1/100) that I'm using for training (I used the [labelMe](https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme) utility):

[shirt_001.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVIy3.jpg)

[shirt_001.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4WKU.png)

**main.py result for mobilenetv2_coco_voc_trainaug (shirt as a person, that's ok) and my custom model** :

[mobilenetv2_coco_voc_trainaug result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBs5z.jpg)

[my custom model result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42S7R.jpg)

As you can see, my model fails. I've been testing many combinations without success. **What should I do?** Thank you!

Comment: Hey! Do you have same results now? I have the same problem, I tried to train my model with different masks (with colors rgb (1,0,0) -> indexed color, rgb(1, 1, 1) -> indexed color, rgb(128, 0, 0) -> indexed color, rgb -> bw), but still no results (after 2 weeks) :(

Comment: Hi, this is the last result with  90000 training_number_of_steps. ->[image result](https://i.ibb.co/5Kpn6FV/Capture.jpg)<-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had the same problem and after many attempts I've done it.
First, you should make correct masks. If you use one class you should create the masks with **indexed color map**, and **all pixels should be 0 or 1**, 0 - background, 1 - mask (there're 255 colors in the indexed color map).
Second, you need a bigger dataset. I tried training using a dataset with ~200 images and got no results (even with a correct dataset) even on checkpoint-30k. But when I tried training using a dataset with 450 images I had some results only from ~9000 epoch. There was no improvement after the ~18000 epoch, but the results were plausible (though far from ideal). Then I was training a model with 1100 images, but the results were the same.

Comment: thank you for your answer. You're right, I increment my data set by ~860 and got very nice results. I started taking samples for shirts. hope this machine throws some good results, I'll share soon.